# Does callable(obj) make an attempt to call?

Tags: python, methods, callable, sonos

I am exploring an API, and using the following to see what methods are available without searching through all attributes by eye with `dir()`:

```
methods = [m for m in dir(kt) if callable(getattr(kt, m))]
```

which throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/soco/core.py", line 103, in inner_function
    raise SoCoSlaveException(message)
soco.exceptions.SoCoSlaveException: The method or property "cross_fade" can only be called/used on the coordinator in a group
```

Ok, so I can't use `cross_fade`, that's fine.  But I didn't try to call it, I was just trying to find out if I could.

I would have thought that `callable()` would be able to check using something similar to `type()`, but it seems like it's attempting to make a call and only catching certain types of exceptions.

I get the same exception when I tried `type(kt.cross_fade)`, and when I just try `>>> kt.cross_fade` in the terminal.

So I guess there are two questions here:  Does `callable` make an attempt to call?  And, what can cause a method to "exist" but be completely unavailable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`callable` doesn't attempt to call the object. It only checks that the object has an implementation of the call operator.

The exception is occurring in the attempt to retrieve the attribute in the first place. Attribute access can be overridden to do just about anything in Python, and the `cross_fade` attribute of this object is implemented as a `property` with an `only_on_master` decorator on the getter that raises an exception if you try to retrieve the attribute on a slave.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the [source code](https://github.com/SoCo/SoCo/blob/06a5e758f65dcb920f72b21353094b468173fa77/soco/core.py#L371), we'll see that `cross_fade` is actually a property:

```
@property
@only_on_master  # Only for symmetry with the setter
def cross_fade(self):
    """The speaker's cross fade state.
    True if enabled, False otherwise
    """
    # ...
```

In turn, the getter is wrapped into [`only_on_master`](https://github.com/SoCo/SoCo/blob/06a5e758f65dcb920f72b21353094b468173fa77/soco/core.py#L96) which is where the exception is raised.